# extending IServiceCollection in asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a class library project, and in that project include some interfaces and classes that implements those interfaces.

After that, I want to provide this class library project, as a nuget package, so, will be ideal having some kind of extension from IServiceCollection, in order to after the nuget installation, with one line of code in the `Startup.cs`, `ConfigureServices()` on the application that is using the nuget, make something like that:

`services.AddServicesFromMyNugetPackage()`

and that method will be execute, based on `IServiceCollection` methods, my configuration for DI.

any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your library, you can create a static class and write some extensions methods where you can register your dependencies as the following example:

```
public static class ServicesExtensions
{
        public static void AddMyLibraryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // register your services here
        }
 }
```

and then in your startup file:

```
services.AddMyLibraryServices();
```

Comment: At what point does AddMyLibraryServices become a member of the service collection?  I am looking at some code that does this now and the startup file does not even use the namespace that the extension method is declared in.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the Configuration in this way `builder.Services.AddMyLibraryServices(builder.Configuration!);` ?

Comment: yes, you can do that. I would recommend passing a custom configuration class instead of the whole configuration.