# Should we extend IServiceCollection in class library project asp .net core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, class-library

I'm trying to understand that in a multi layer project where we should register dependencies. I'm using ASP .NET Core to create a project which will have a Web application and 3 or more logical layers(class libraries) lets say Business Layer, Data Access Layer etc. Business Layer can have 1 or more classes and so the other layers.

My question is should I register all the dependency(of all the classes of the class libraries) in startup class(by extending IServiceCollection) of web application.

like:

```
namespace Architecture.Web.DependencyExtension
{
    public static class BusinessLayerDependency
    {
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterDependency(this IServiceCollection service)
        {
            // register dependency for classes of business libraries here 
            service.AddTransient<IOrderBizObj, OrderBizObj>();
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

Or should I extend the IServiceCollection into class libraries and do the registration as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761348/extending-iservicecollection-in-asp-net-core)?

When I go through [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) It is saying that all the dependency should be register at the composition root of the application. It also motioned that "The Composition Root can be spread out across multiple classes as long as they all reside in a single module".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want wrap a bunch of similar services together, it makes sense, if you want to do it all from the root that is fine as well. There is no right and wrong here, what makes sense to you... and the good thing is you can always change it if you change your mind

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for your answer. I think, if we register the dependency in a class of library and later on we want to use that library in a different project with another kind of Dependency Injection then that may cause an issue. What do you think?